# protractor getCssValue('background') returns several info

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I my code I have:

```
expect(element(by.className('nea-navbar')).getCssValue('background')).toBe('#264367');
```

When I run, the expect returns:

- `Expected 'rgb(38, 67, 103) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box' to be '#264367'.`

Do you know with it returns so many info and how to pass from rgb to hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's passing back the entire background property, whereas you just want background-color:

```
expect(element(by.className('nea-navbar')).getCssValue('background-color')).toBe(...);
```

Your second question on converting rgb to hex has an answer here:
[RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

...and this library also claims to support that:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rgb-hex